# Bind to a string instead of a physical property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I want to create a way of binding to an object with a property name that doesn't actually exist. The model will accept the property name as an argument and return another model somewhat like a dictionary.  I have an idea for a very extensible MVVM solution, but it won't be possible if I have to bind to a physically existing property. I want to do something like the following:

```
<Grid DataContext="{my:MetaBinding Path=SomePropertyName Source={StaticResource MetaModel}">
</Grid>
```

Herein, `Path` is the name of the property and `Source` is the dictionary like model that provides a model (i.e. view model) appropriate to the given `Path` string.

I know this is a stretch but it will be awesome if I can make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about using a wrapper instead? E.g. `Wrapper<T>` that implements `INotifyPropertyChange` with a property named `Value`.  It could be used to bind to a string by passing the string in the constructor.  The only caveat is that you'll be binding to `Value` instead of whatever property name you want.

Comment: Interesting idea, but not quite what I'm trying to do. I'm thinking in terms of data context binding between views and view models using view names.

Comment: I see.  After reading your question and your comment I'm still a little fuzzy on your idea though.  Perhaps some psuedo code would help?

Comment: My goal is to have a meta-model that serves view models to views based upon string-valued names. The view model binds to the view via a `MetaBinding` custom mark-up extension.